# How to debug GWT client code in JBoss?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, jboss

I am working on a Java/J2EE web project in which all GUI is developed in GWT(V2.5.1). We have deployed WAR files in JBoss 7.1. Now I want to debug the UI/client side code in eclipse Luna(4.4). I have tried a lots of ways to debug but not successful. Is there any way/third party tool/eclipse plugin to debug the GWT code. Please help me to debug the code. Thanks in advance. (Also let me know the way of logging in GWT).

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug GWT client code once it is deployed as a war.
You can only debug using SuperDevMode using the debugging tools of the browser (I prefer Chrome for this).

Logging is done using java.util.Logger after putting some stuff in your gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<inherits name="be.gps.gwt.shared.Shared"/>

<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>

<replace-with class="be.gps.gwt.jsonrpclogger.client.JsonRpcRemoteLogHandler">
  <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.logging.client.SimpleRemoteLogHandler" />
    <any>
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    </any>
</replace-with>
```